# Error running ceph-deploy install

Tags: centos, ceph

I have been following the following tutorial to setup ceph on CentOS

https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/Storage/ceph-Quickstart

When I try to run `ceph-deploy` to install to my other nodes, I get the following error:

```
[ceph-deploy@ceph-admin ~]$ ceph-deploy install --osd ceph-osd0
[ceph_deploy.conf][DEBUG ] found configuration file at: /home/ceph-deploy/.cephdeploy.conf
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] Invoked (1.5.25): /usr/bin/ceph-deploy install --osd ceph-osd0
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Installing stable version hammer on cluster ceph hosts ceph-osd0
[ceph_deploy.install][DEBUG ] Detecting platform for host ceph-osd0 ...
The authenticity of host 'ceph-osd0 (192.168.1.165)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:1+7yHggQ/bSRni+cSrEs6L+eY4rywVCl+c24G6feh/M.
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:5e:e1:00:1b:ff:ac:6d:60:a2:fa:d6:f0:23:6c:26:94.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ceph-osd0,192.168.1.165' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] connection detected need for sudo
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] connected to host: ceph-osd0
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] detect platform information from remote host
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] detect machine type
[ceph_deploy.install][INFO  ] Distro info: CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 Core
[ceph-osd0][INFO  ] installing ceph on ceph-osd0
[ceph-osd0][INFO  ] Running command: sudo yum clean all
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Cleaning repos: base centos-ceph-nautilus centos-nfs-ganesha28 epel extras
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]               : updates
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
[ceph-osd0][INFO  ] adding EPEL repository
[ceph-osd0][INFO  ] Running command: sudo yum -y install epel-release
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Determining fastest mirrors
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * base: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * centos-ceph-nautilus: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * centos-nfs-ganesha28: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * epel: linux-mirrors.fnal.gov
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * extras: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * updates: linux-mirrors.fnal.gov
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Resolving Dependencies
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] --> Running transaction check
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-11 will be updated
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-12 will be an update
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] --> Finished Dependency Resolution
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Dependencies Resolved
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ================================================================================
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  Package                Arch             Version           Repository      Size
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ================================================================================
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Updating:
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  epel-release           noarch           7-12              epel            15 k
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Transaction Summary
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ================================================================================
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Upgrade  1 Package
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Total download size: 15 k
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Downloading packages:
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Running transaction check
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Running transaction test
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Transaction test succeeded
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Running transaction
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   Updating   : epel-release-7-12.noarch                                     1/2
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   Cleanup    : epel-release-7-11.noarch                                     2/2
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   Verifying  : epel-release-7-12.noarch                                     1/2
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   Verifying  : epel-release-7-11.noarch                                     2/2
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Updated:
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   epel-release.noarch 0:7-12                                                    
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Complete!
[ceph-osd0][INFO  ] Running command: sudo yum -y install yum-priorities
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * base: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * centos-ceph-nautilus: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * centos-nfs-ganesha28: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * epel: linux-mirrors.fnal.gov
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * extras: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  * updates: linux-mirrors.fnal.gov
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Resolving Dependencies
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] --> Running transaction check
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ---> Package yum-plugin-priorities.noarch 0:1.1.31-52.el7 will be installed
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] --> Finished Dependency Resolution
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Dependencies Resolved
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ================================================================================
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  Package                     Arch         Version              Repository  Size
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ================================================================================
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Installing:
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]  yum-plugin-priorities       noarch       1.1.31-52.el7        base        29 k
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Transaction Summary
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] ================================================================================
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Install  1 Package
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Total download size: 29 k
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Installed size: 28 k
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Downloading packages:
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Running transaction check
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Running transaction test
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Transaction test succeeded
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Running transaction
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   Installing : yum-plugin-priorities-1.1.31-52.el7.noarch                   1/1
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   Verifying  : yum-plugin-priorities-1.1.31-52.el7.noarch                   1/1
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Installed:
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]   yum-plugin-priorities.noarch 0:1.1.31-52.el7                                  
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ]
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Complete!
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Configure Yum priorities to include obsoletes
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] check_obsoletes has been enabled for Yum priorities plugin
[ceph-osd0][INFO  ] Running command: sudo rpm --import https://ceph.com/git/?p=ceph.git;a=blob_plain;f=keys/release.asc
[ceph-osd0][INFO  ] Running command: sudo rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs http://ceph.com/rpm-hammer/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Retrieving http://ceph.com/rpm-hammer/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <html> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <head><title>Index failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of /rpm-hammer/</title></head> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <body failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of bgcolor=white> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <h1>Index failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of /rpm-hammer/</h1><hr><pre><a failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of href=../>../</a> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <a failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of href=el6/>el6/</a> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 24-Apr-2016 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 00:05 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: -: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <a failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of href=el7/>el7/</a> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 29-Aug-2016 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 11:53 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: -: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <a failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of href=fc20/>fc20/</a> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 07-Apr-2015 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 19:21 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: -: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <a failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of href=rhel6/>rhel6/</a> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 07-Apr-2015 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of 19:22 failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: -: not an rpm package (or package manifest):
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of </pre><hr></body> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of </html> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 32
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: Failed to execute command: rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs http://ceph.com/rpm-hammer/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command is failing because a URL doesn't exist:

```
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] RuntimeError: Failed to execute command: rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs http://ceph.com/rpm-hammer/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
```

An indicator is that HTML code is spilling into the script:

```
[ceph-osd0][DEBUG ] Retrieving http://ceph.com/rpm-hammer/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <html> failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of <head><title>Index failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of of failed: No such file or directory
[ceph-osd0][WARNIN] error: open of /rpm-hammer/</title></head> failed: No such file or directory
```

The URL should instead be `http://download.ceph.com/rpm-hammer/el7/noarch/ceph-release-1-0.el7.noarch.rpm` (the subdomain `download` was missing from the original URL)

To fix this, change the URL in the file `lib/python2.7/site-packages/ceph_deploy/hosts/centos/install.py` on the admin node, and re-run the command.